# selenium webdriver connection problems (not connected to DevTools)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I am running a Selenium webdriver program that needs a lot of time to complete. My problem is that, for some reason, whenever I run this script as a headless browser, I end up having issues. For example, if I use Firefox driver I get this after a short time:

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=58161): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/1aa9d459-8770-41ec-a25b-a1a9be8f7d2b/elements (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x1817268d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
```

If I use Chrome's webdriver, the script does run much longer, but I always end up encountering this error:

```
disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
  (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)
```

As for the second error, I have seen this can happen due to having too many elements to load in a page, which is not the case, as the URLs where the driver stops are pages that in previous iterations have been loaded without any issue. I have also read this may happen because of not having interaction with the page for a long amount of time, but that is not the case either, as I am interacting with the page continuously (by typing on fields or clicking on elements).

I have tried to catch the `WebDriverException` and restart the driver by doing the following:

```
print(" ........ Restarting webdriver ...... ")
current_url = driver.current_url
driver.quit()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--auto-show-cursor')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
driver.get(current_url)
```

Nevertheless, even if I do catch the exception, this does not prevent the script from failing and finishing the execution abruptly. Is there any way in which I can reconnect when something like this happens so that my script continues with the execution? I am using python, by the way.

Comment: These are always difficult problems. If the web driver is at fault, you could kill the web driver process (like ChromeDriver.exe), but that usually kills the web browser. You could start Chrome.exe separately, and then try attaching your web driver to that. I don't recall off the top of my head what that code looks like though.